# Beautiful Soup in Python: extracting different data with the same classes

Tags: python, class, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract via Beautiful Soup different data from the same web page, but apparently all the data are with the same html info.
The web page is https://www.ine.es
What I am trying to get is: 47.329.981, -0,5 and -22,1.
I don't know if it is possible having the same class (the only different are the images).
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Check this out

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url="https://www.ine.es"
results=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(results.text,"html.parser")
details=soup.findAll("span",attrs={"class":"dato"})
for i in details:
    print(i.text)
```

Output: 47.329.981   -0,5   -22,1   15,33   55,54

Comment: Exactly, but if I wanna get just the second or third value I believe I couldn't. But I know that you mean, I don't need to get it individually, just the whole of it, insert in a list and then select the values individually from the list. Thank you very much for all.

Comment: @macbeto if you find this answer helpful please do accept it so that it may help others in future